# Extracting the indices of outliers in Linear Regression

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, statistics, scipy

The following script computes R-squared value between two numpy arrays(x and y).

The R-squared value is very low due to outliers in the data. How can I extract the indices of those outliers?

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, scipy.stats as stats

x = np.random.random_integers(1,50,50)
y = np.random.random_integers(1,50,50)

r2 = stats.linregress(x, y) [3]**2
print r2

plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Sander's approach is the correct one, but if you must see R2 without those outliers before making a decision here is a way to do it.

Setup data and introduce outlier:

```
In [1]:
import numpy as np, scipy.stats as stats
np.random.seed(123)

x = np.random.random_integers(1,50,50)
y = np.random.random_integers(1,50,50)   
y[5] = 100
```

Calculate R2 taking out one `y` value at a time (along with matching `x` value):

```
m = np.eye(y.shape[0])
r2 = np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: stats.linregress(np.delete(x, a.argmax()), np.delete(y, a.argmax()))[3]**2, 0, m)
```

Get index of the biggest outlier:

```
r2.argmax()

Out[1]:
5
```

Get R2 when this outlier is taken out:

```
In [2]:
r2[r2.argmax()]

Out[2]:
0.85892084723588935
```

Get the value of the outlier:

```
In [3]:
y[r2.argmax()]

Out[3]:
100
```

To get top `n` outliers:

```
In [4]:
n = 5
sorted_index = r2.argsort()[::-1]
sorted_index[:n]

Out [4]:
array([ 5, 27, 34,  0, 17], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get index of more than one (say 5) biggest outliers?

Comment: The `r2` is a normal `ndarray`, so you can do all the usual sorting, slicing..., and even plotting to visually see how R2 changes for each value. I have added example to get `n` biggest outliers.

Answer (score 5):

An outlier is defined as: value-mean > 2*standard deviation.
You can do this with the line

```
[i for i in range(len(x)) if (abs(x[i] - np.mean(x)) > 2*np.std(x))]
```

What is does:
A list is constructed from the indices of x, where the element at that index satisfies the condition described above.

A quick test:

```
x = np.random.random_integers(1,50,50)
```

this gives me the array:

```
array([16,  6, 13, 18, 21, 37, 31,  8,  1, 48,  4, 40,  9, 14,  6, 45, 20,
       15, 14, 32, 30,  8, 19,  8, 34, 22, 49,  5, 22, 23, 39, 29, 37, 24,
       45, 47, 21,  5,  4, 27, 48,  2, 22,  8, 12,  8, 49, 12, 15, 18])
```

Now I add some outliers manually as there are none initially:

```
x[4] = 200
x[15] = 178
```

lets test:

```
[i for i in range(len(x)) if (abs(x[i] - np.mean(x)) > 2*np.std(x))]
```

result:

```
[4, 15]
```

Is this what you was looking for?

**EDIT:**
I added the abs() function in the line above, because when you are working with negative numbers this might end bad. The abs() function takes the absolute value.

Comment: List comprehension isn't required. `np.nonzero(np.abs(x) - np.mean(x) > 2 * np.std(x))` will return the indices, and `x[np.abs(x) - np.mean(x) > 2 * np.std(x)]` will return an array with the values.